# Converting JSON to PHP Array

Tags: php, json

I'm sending a JSON post to PHP that contains multiple items.  My JSON looks like this:

```
 [
    {
        "request": "submitTicket",
        "id": "3",
        "delivLoc": "1 COLORADO CITY",
        "estimatedBarrels": "123.0",
        "facilityID": "T666778",
        "highDegreeF": "0.0",
        "highOilFeet": "0"
    },
    {
        "request": "submitTicket",
        "id": "4",
        "delivLoc": "1 COLORADO CITY",
        "estimatedBarrels": "143.0",
        "facilityID": "T666778",
        "highDegreeF": "0.0",
        "highOilFeet": "0"
    },
    {
        "request": "submitTicket",
        "id": "5",
        "delivLoc": "1 COLORADO CITY",
        "estimatedBarrels": "122.0",
        "facilityID": "T666778",
        "highDegreeF": "0.0",
        "highOilFeet": "0"
    }
]
```

I've been trying to use json_decode() in PHP but it comes back null which causes the foreach loop to fail.  Why is the decode not working?

Actually this JSON gets back slashes put in it when arriving to PHP.  I took those out before posting here and also tried running it with stripslashes().

Comment: could you please show the result of `var_dump`/`print_r` of variable you're trying to json_decode?

Comment: in android or php? http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?  "`NULL` is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit."  Your JSON is likely malformed.

Comment: The JSON comes from Android, and I'm trying to decode in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
$data ='[

{"request":"submitTicket","id":"3","delivLoc":"1 COLORADO CITY","estimatedBarrels":"123.0","facilityID":"T666778","highDegreeF":"0.0","highOilFeet":"0"},
{"request":"submitTicket","id":"4","delivLoc":"1 COLORADO CITY","estimatedBarrels":"143.0","facilityID":"T666778","highDegreeF":"0.0","highOilFeet":"0"},
{"request":"submitTicket","id":"5","delivLoc":"1 COLORADO CITY","estimatedBarrels":"122.0","facilityID":"T666778","highDegreeF":"0.0","highOilFeet":"0"}

]';

$jsonarray=json_decode($data,true);
print_r($jsonarray);
```

Comment: That worked as a test, but when I say:  $data = json_decode($_POST['json'], true); then $data always comes back null.

Comment: confrim your post properly coming or not ,like print_r($_POST['json'])

Comment: Jocker, I confirmed this and it is coming over but with back slashes before each quote.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after playing with everybody's suggestions.  I had to remove the slashes from the post before trying to decode the JSON.  I decoded to PHP array like this:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['json']));
```

I suppose it was too late last night, and I some how overlooked this.  Thanks everybody for your help and quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

**Output:**

```
 object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i can see is the actual data which is passing may be not valid json.

just assign the data in a variable and use like this

```
var data = [{
        "request": "submitTicket",
        "id": "3",
        "delivLoc": "1 COLORADO CITY",
        "estimatedBarrels": "123.0",
        "facilityID": "T666778",
        "highDegreeF": "0.0",
        "highOilFeet": "0"
    },
    {
        "request": "submitTicket",
        "id": "4",
        "delivLoc": "1 COLORADO CITY",
        "estimatedBarrels": "143.0",
        "facilityID": "T666778",
        "highDegreeF": "0.0",
        "highOilFeet": "0"
    },
    {
        "request": "submitTicket",
        "id": "5",
        "delivLoc": "1 COLORADO CITY",
        "estimatedBarrels": "122.0",
        "facilityID": "T666778",
        "highDegreeF": "0.0",
        "highOilFeet": "0"
    }
]
```

and then pass this with the ajax(I assume you are using ajax) in data part something like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:[your url],
    data:data,
    ....
});
```

hope this will work